# Check if data has been received socket c#

Tags: c#, sockets

When sending async data in a socket with `Socket.BeginSend()`, this will send data to the conneted client or server, now this works fine, but now when i pulled out the network cable and send something again, it does not give away any error,

- The `Socket.EndSend()` does not throw an exception
- Socketerror returns succes
- socket.Connected is true

now i know that it is no guarantee that the data has been send when a sendCallback happens becouse of buffering but how can i check if the data that has been send actualy has been send and received?

Comment: I 'm not sure how this would be possible in the common case (TCP connection, unplug cable then send), but I can offer this at least: you cannot **ever** be sure the data has been received by the target process unless it sends you an acknowledgement manually and you successfully receive it. Which raises the question how can it be sure that *you* received the acknowledgement, etc etc.

Comment: How do you mean isnt possible? the socket does not know if the cable is unplugged becouse it doesnt activly send data to the other socket to check if it is still there, i think thats why i can send to the remote host, the only weird thing is that it does not check if the host is still there before returning that it has done a succesfull send.

Comment: Didn't you say you unplug the cable and *then* send? If so, it does actively send data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP/IP cannot guarantee that all data that have been sent will also be received. But even if it would guarantee it that is not what you need. What sender actually needs is to know if it does not have to send data again, and that usually implies if sent data has been *processed* on receivers side.

If sender needs to know this then communication protocol **must** be changed so that sender can receive a confirmation by the receiver that it can safely assume that data has been processed. Also, sender **must** at certain point proclaim a time-out (and close the socket) if receiver did not send back the confirmation on time (and in your code you **must** decide what to do about it, maybe save data to be sent at later time, or raise an alert to the user). Also receiver **must** handle the situation where the same data is being sent twice (as last item in previous connection, and as another item in new connection) and not treat this data as two distinct pieces of data.

I can elaborate more on each of these "musts" if required. Communication is hard.

Comment: Ok, so if i do a Socket.Send() this data will be placed in a buffer, and from here it is not clear to my program what happens to it, the tcp/ip tries to succesfully send the data, and if any errors it could be possible that only half the stream is received. for example if the tcp tries to send packets 1,2,3,4,5 and after 1,4 and 2 have been succesfully received by the remote computer, a network failure happens and the others can not be send anymore. the receiving end will only be able to read packet 1 and 2? and if i would like some info back i would have to do that with a protocol i write?

Comment: Correct. TCP/IP guarantees only the ordering on receiving side, so receiver gets only 1 and 2. Both sender and receiver may get a socket error at some point, but there are border situations when no error occurs even though the communication is halted. Therefore you need user based time out functionality.